# css hover animation is not working in ie11. CSS transition on hovering over an element not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, css-transitions

I'm making an animation on the hover.
It works fine in , Chrome Safari and FireFox. But not working in IE.
please help this problem

```
a {
      color: white;
      font-size: 13px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
      display: block;
    }

    a:hover {
      margin-right: 25px;
      background: red;

    }

    a::after {
      content: url(../../images/ICON_DOWNLOAD.png);
      position: absolute;
      right: -30px;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    a:hover::after {
      right: 15px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code with IE 11 browser and animation is working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>

<style>
a {
      color: white;
      font-size: 13px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
      display: block;
    }

    a:hover {
      margin-right: 25px;
      background: red;

    }

    a::after {
      content: url(https://i.postimg.cc/c4QJc7R1/down.png);
      position: absolute;
      right: -30px;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    a:hover::after {
      right: 15px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">This is link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

If you are using any older version of IE then it is recommended to upgrade to iE 11 version.

Let me know if I misunderstand anything from your above description, I will try to correct myself.

Answer (score 1):

The only help I can offer you is to switch to IE9 or above.  The `:after` psuedoelement is not supported until that version.  It's always a good idea to check for support when dealing with IE bugs.

https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter